Multiplication by a regular function in a negative Sobolev space seen as an adjoint
I'm trying to understand a statement by Reed and Simon in Volume II of their Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, section IX.6: Elliptic regularity.
They denote by $W_m$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$, the $m$-th Sobolev space which would be, I believe, nowadays called $H^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$, defined as the set of tempered distributions $T$ whose Fourier transform $\widehat{T}$ is a measurable function satisfying:
$$\|T\|^2_{W_m} := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(1 + |\lambda|^2\right)^m |\widehat{T}(\lambda)|^2 \mathrm{d}\lambda < \infty$$
I also understand fairly well how they identify $W_{-m}$ to $W_m^*$ via the following isometric isomorphism: $$T \in W_{-m} \quad\longmapsto\quad \Lambda_T := \left(S \in W_m \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{T}(-\lambda) \widehat{S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda\right)$$
However my question comes in almost immediately after: there is a Proposition $1$ about $W_m$ actually corresponding to the usual definition of a Sobolev space using the $L^2$ norms of the derivatives for $m$ nonnegative integer, and then this one:

Proposition $2$: Let $m$ be an integer. If $T \in W_m$ and $\varphi \in C^{|m|}$ with bounded derivatives [where I think that $\varphi$ is also assumed to be itself bounded], then $\varphi T \in W_m$.
Proof: If $m \geq 0$, then the conclusion follows from Leibniz's rule and Proposition $1$. [This is fine for me]
If $m < 0$, multiplication by $\varphi$ on $W_m$ is the adjoint of multiplication by $\varphi$ on $W_{|m|}$ under the natural identification of $W_m$ and $W^*_{|m|}$. Thus multiplication by $\varphi$ is bounded.

This might be quite simple, but I'm afraid I'm not quite confident about whether I correctly interpreted their statement about multiplication being an adjoint to the same multiplication but on the corresponding dual Sobolev space.
More precisely, I was wondering whether I was misusing/misremembering properties of the Fourier transform over tempered distributions in the calculations below. $W_m$ is a space of functions for nonnegative $m$, and the Fourier transforms are assumed to be measurable functions for all the Sobolev spaces too, but $T$ doesn't have to be (the Dirac delta and its derivatives are in the negative Sobolev spaces, right?), so I assume I should change something?
Proof attempt: If I denote by $\varphi_m$ the operator $T \in W_m \mapsto \varphi T \in W_m$, then I know that it's bounded for $m$ a nonnegative integer as a consequence of the proof of the first half of the proposition (with the operator norm being expressed relative to the $\infty$-norms of the derivatives of $\varphi$), and the adjoint/transpose of $\varphi_m$ is, using the previous identification:
$$(\varphi_m)^* : \Lambda_T \in W_{-m} \,\longmapsto\, \Lambda_T \circ \varphi_m = \left(S \in W_m \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{T}(-\lambda) \widehat{\varphi S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda\right) \in W_{-m}$$
However, we have:
$$\begin{split} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{T}(-\lambda) \widehat{\varphi S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{\widehat{\overline{T}}(\lambda)} \widehat{\varphi S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{\overline{T}(\lambda)} (\varphi S)(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda \quad \text{by unitarity of the $L^2$-Fourier transform}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{\overline{(\varphi T)}(\lambda)} S(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \overline{\widehat{\overline{\varphi T}}(\lambda)} \widehat{S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda \quad \text{idem}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\varphi T}(-\lambda) \widehat{S}(\lambda) \mathrm{d}\lambda
\end{split}$$
Thus we do have: $$(\varphi_m)^*(T) = \Lambda_{\varphi T} = \Lambda_{\varphi_{-m}(T)} (\approx \varphi_{-m}(T))$$

I have decided to completely remake my answer. I was overcomplicating the problem way too much by overanalysing the statement from the authors...
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^m(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $D^\alpha \varphi$ is bounded for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$, and $T \in H^{-m}(\mathbb{R}^d) = W_{-m}$.
Then, define $\varphi T$ as the linear functional $S \in H^m \mapsto T(\varphi S) \,\,(= \Lambda_T(\varphi S)) \in \mathbb{C}$, which is well-defined because we know that $\varphi S$ belongs to $H^m$ for all $S \in H^m$, with $\|\varphi S\|_{H^m} \leq C_\varphi \|S\|_{H^m}$.
Note that $\varphi T$ was not already well-defined as a distribution because $\varphi$ is not $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.
Now, we have:
$$|\varphi T(S)| = |T(\varphi S)| \leq \|T\|_{H^{-m}} \|\varphi S\|_{H^m} \leq \|T\|_{H^{-m}} C_\varphi \|S\|_{H^m}$$
and $\varphi T$ is a continuous linear functional on $H^m$, hence $\varphi T \in H^{-m}$.
I was so fixated on the idea that Reed and Simon wanted to prove that multiplication by $\varphi$ in one space was adjoint to multiplication by $\varphi$ in the other space in order to show that $\varphi T$ belonged in $H^{-m}$ that I was missing the fact that they intended it to be a definition exactly like for usual distributions or for tempered distributions...

The $W_m$ stands for $H^{2m}$ not $H^m$. And so the Proposition should be modified as $\varphi \in C^{2|m|}$.
I don't think checking the result in the Fourier side is reasonable. You should think of $\varphi\in C^m$ implies $[f\mapsto \varphi f]:H^m(\Bbb R^n)\to H^m(\Bbb R^n)$ for $m\ge0$. Once this is prove, use the property that multiplication map is symmetric, i.e. $\langle\varphi T,\psi\rangle=\langle T,\varphi\psi\rangle$, we can get $[f\mapsto \varphi f]:H^{-m}(\Bbb R^n)\to H^{-m}(\Bbb R^n)$
The best way to prove this is to apply product rules and the product map $L^2\times L^\infty\to L^2$ is bounded.

Ah my bad, I forgot the square modulus in the definition of the norm... How did I manage to forget that...

I think proving the symmetry of the multiplication map on $H^m$ is exactly what I'm looking for... I guess if the Schwartz class is dense in the positive Sobolev spaces I could just do what I did but with duality brackets and $S$ replaced by $\psi$ Schwartz, and then use density to extend the equality to the whole of $H^m$?

You can thnk about approximate varphi as well.
